# create shortcut to run python app using anaconda env

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, shortcut

So downloaded an app from github, and set up a conda env to run it. I can run the app without problem when i open my anaconda prompt, activate my environment, and then run the app.py file. Now, i want to have a shortcut to do all these things. Usually when i do this with a non conda environment, i juste create a windows shortcut with the following parameters:

```
{location of my environment} {location of the python file i want to run}
```

Now, i'm still not very familiar with the conda envs, and when i do the same thing with a conda env, it dosen't work. I tried to put these lines in a batch file:

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\remic\Documents\storage\python\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat chunkmogrify
cd C:/Users/remic/Documents/storage/python/projects/2mp/chunkmogrify
python app.py
```

the first line is supposed to activate the chunkmogrify conda environment (this line works)

the second navigate to the location of the app.py file

and the third is supposed to run the app.py file.
The issue is that only the first line seems to work because when i run my .bat file, i get this:

[image: Output of the .bat file]

So the environment is activated, but the location hasn't changed and the app does not run.

Therefore I wanted to know what i did wrong, or if you had another idea on how to setup this kind of shortcuts.

The end goal is to have a shortcut so that i can run app.py like any other software, but from the source python code without having to build an executable for the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'conda run' instead of 'conda activate'. E.g.

> <path_to_conda.exe> run -n <env_name> python <path_to_python>

So for you:

> C:/Users/remic/Documents/storage/anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe run -n chunkmogrify python C:/Users/remic/Documents/storage/python/projects/2mp/chunkmogrify/app.py